# Angular Identifier 'playerPhoto' is not defined. '' does not contain such a member

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am working on an ionic app, where I am fetching value using *ngFor="let playerValue of players", in HTML file

But I am getting error on using property of playerValue like playerPhoto or playerType in html while interpolation {{playerValue.playerPhoto}} or playerValue.playerType eg : -

or

> error message is -:
>
> [Angular] Identifier 'playerType' is not defined. '' does not contain
>   such a member
>
> or
>
> [Angular] Identifier 'playerPhoto' is not defined. '' does not contain
>   such a member

**NOTE:** ->> WHEN I REMOVE CODE PIPES FROM   
    WHICH IS - |
          search : terms| sort: {property: column, order: order};

ERROR IS NOT SHOWN , SO PROBLEM IS WITH ADDING PIPES

Below is the HTML where I am getting error

```
<ion-content no-padding>
  <div class="create-team-section">
    <ion-list class="team-create-list">
      <div [ngSwitch]="playerType" *ngFor="let playerValue of players |
          search : terms| sort: {property: column, order: order}; let i = index">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="playerValue.playerType" ngSelected="selected">
          <ion-item [class.active]="playerValue.isSelected? 'active' : null">
            <ion-grid no-padding>
              <!-- <a (click)="playerInfo()"><img src={{playerValue.playerPhoto}}></a> -->
              <ion-row align-items-center [class.shake]="shake==playerValue.playerUid ? 'shake' : null">
                <ion-col col-3>
                  <!-- <div class="create-team-imge" >
                      <img src={{playerValue.playerPhoto}}>
                    </div> -->
                  <div class="create-team-imge">
                    <ion-avatar item-star no-line>
                      <button (click)="playerinfo(i)"><img src={{playerValue.playerPhoto}}></button>
                    </ion-avatar>
                    <ion-badge>
                      <ion-icon name="information"></ion-icon>
                    </ion-badge>
                  </div>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-md-9 col-9 (click)="setClickedRow(i)">
                  <ion-row align-items-center>
                    <ion-col col-md-8 col-7>

                      <p>{{playerValue.playerName}}</p>
                      <p>Selected By {{playerValue.selectedBy}}</p>
                      <p class="country" >{{playerValue.teamName}}</p>
                      <p class="points"> Points:
                        <span>{{playerValue.totalPoint}}</span>
                      </p>
                    </ion-col>
                    <ion-col col-md-4 col-5 class="cradit">
                      <p>
                        <span>{{playerValue.playerCreditPoint}}</span>
                      </p>
                      <button ion-button icon-only>
                        <ion-icon [name]="playerValue.isSelected? 'close' : 'ios-checkmark'"></ion-icon>
                      </button>
                    </ion-col>
                  </ion-row>
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
          </ion-item>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

ts file

```
**export class CreateteamPage {
  players: playerss [];**
```

in typescript I have put players of interface type player[] ,

INTERFACE

```
 export interface Playerss {
      playerUid: string;
      playerName: string;
      playerPhoto: string;
      country: string;
      playerCreditPoint: any;
      playerType: string;
      teamName: string;
      flag: number;
      totalPoint: number;
      status: boolean;
      selectedBy: string;
      c: string;
      vc: string;
      isSelected: boolean;
  }
```

**JSON DATA ->**

http://magicmindpremier11.azurewebsites.net/api/Players/GetPlayers

Comment: Add a return type for `sort` pipe as `Playerss[]`

Comment: @xyz how to add that in , should we create a function for that in ts file

Comment: Please provide the code of your pipes